# Making a dynamic microsoft power bi report for every company

Tags: angular, powerbi

I'm working in a dashboard of KPIs , well it contains some power bi reports.There is a dropdown with it you can change the company, so do i have to do 2 differents reports for every company or can i make just one parametrable report?

Comment: How are you delivering the report, you has tagged angular are you using Power BI Embedded?

Comment: i'm using the iframe generated by power bi                             <iframe width="800" height="600" src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>

Answer (score 1):

If the report is a standard report that will deployed across a number of customers, I would suggest that you use [row level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-rls) to filter the report based on the logged in user. You'll need to create a table of user to the company, then set up the filtering across the table. The Microsoft article gives a good outline on how to do this.

If that is not an option, you can deploy a report per customer, and [set a parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-parameters) in Power Query, with a 'default' value, maybe one which returns no data so you don't accidentally return a customers data. You can then set the real parameter in the service and deploy the report in the iframe to the customer.

Another option is to filter the report at the [url setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-url-filters), that will pass a filter to the generic report, in your case to a customer.

Of the above options, Row Level Security will give the best & most secure option.

Hope that helps